# How can I run ikvm with mono on MacOS

Tags: macos, mono, ikvm

I would like to compile/run a java library in .NET.

I found this tutorial with a good example but it is not applicable for MacOs
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/java/

I installed the Mono MDK which should come with ikvm but I can't find ikvm on my system only the ikvm libs.

```
macfly:w v$ locate ikvm
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.8.0/lib/libikvm-native.dylib
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.8.0/lib/libikvm-native.dylib.dSYM
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.8.0/lib/libikvm-native.dylib.dSYM/Contents
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.8.0/lib/libikvm-native.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.8.0/lib/libikvm-native.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.8.0/lib/libikvm-native.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.8.0/lib/libikvm-native.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libikvm-native.dylib
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.8.0/lib/libikvm-native.la
```

where is ikvm on macos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ikvm executable is not part of Mono anymore.